# drupal_get_js(), when using AJAX

Tags: ajax

I’m using `ajax_links_api` and for some reason it doesn’t work as expected. When I load page through AJAX I want to include .js files which weren’t already included in a page using `<script>` tag.

I am doing it through behavior.

Using `Drupal.settings.ajaxPageState.js` I can obtain list of .js files that I want to include, but some of them have been already included, so I want to avoid duplicates.

How can I get the list of files which were already included?
`drupal_get_js()` won’t work because it is AJAX.

And after I get the list of the files that I want to include, how can I include them?